# UWP Windows 10.0.15063 Phone Emulator can't connect to Internet - VS2017

Tags: uwp, emulation, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I'm using visual studio 2017, trying to connect to internet using the emulator I dont know what happened, when i was using VS2015 I could connect to internet using the emulator but now with 2017 It seems I cant connect to internet so i wont be able to test internet function for my app like getting tables information from my azure mobile app service.

Anyways I had tried configure Hyper-V Virtual Switch Manager - Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch
 by changing from internal to external and using a TP-Link adapter as a different wi-fi source instead of my laptop antena, but even that doesnt seems to work.

It break my emulator causing a DEP6100: The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage.

and it break the emulator to a point where i had to use XdeCleanup.exe to make it work again.

If someone could please help me, If I had a windows phone i would test it directly from device but unfortunately i dont. I'm freelance and new on UWP.

Comment: Try this method [Why can’t the Windows Phone Emulator go online?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2013/10/01/why-cant-the-windows-phone-emulator-go-online/)

Comment: It doesnt help me at all, It says that I should contact my IT provider to accept my emulator, and I know it isnt a issue from my IT provider, because it works on VS2015. besides I had already tried!!

Comment: Try by just deleting your VM on Hyper-V and allow VS to create one while running

Comment: I had already done it, like 20 times today!!! i'm trying different things now, but cant make it work!!! it so frustrating!!

Comment: Do you have "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch" as well as a Virtual Switch that has the same name as the driver of the device that accesses the internet (ethernet or wifi)?

Comment: I have Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch and Microsoft Emulator NAT Switch, they both have three option at hyper V External, Internal and Private, Internal is chosen by default and I had left them like that. I've tried to set them to external but everytime I ran the emulator from VS2017 they are reseted to their default settings I had made it work from hyper V only, to get internet working by using external but from VS2017 its imposible. it resets them back to default. access to internet is with both wifi or ethernet, the result is the same with VS2017